# read binary data from txt file and store in byte datatype

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

I'm creating a program that converts a image to binary data and stores it in txt file and sends the txt file to another person.The other person will select this file from openfiledialog box and then convert it back to image.So i'm stuck at reading the txt file and storing it in a byte[] file and then convert it to image.

Comment: what you have tried? give some code

Comment: Did you try anything? show some effort == code..

Comment: Hi sorry guys i'm new to c# but have read this from msdn but that only display it on screen how can i save it to byte file http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: To write into file you can use the `StreamWriter` class. This is quite popular task so I can't see any reason why you couldn't find it by yourself. But here you go:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287548(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

use this..

```
byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("filepath");
System.IO.MemoryStream imgStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
imgStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
System.Drawing.Image img;
img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgStream);
//use this image as Image of pictureBox
```